# Debug Console links not working in vscode

Tags: flutter, logging, vscode-debugger

In my vs-code, I used the logger plugin in Flutter packages to set logs into my Flutter project. previously in my VS-code, loggers were hit, and showed me the links, where the logs were hit. and I was able to click, the Ctrl+ link, the file and the location where the log is hit are shown, but now it is not working. links are not clikble. i reseted the all setting, but broblem is still there. how can i solve this?
[debug console links not clickble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmTpZ.png)

i need to click on the debug link and rederect to the file and the code line that logger is created.